# How can i cancel/abort an installation from msi which was started with MsiInstallProduct

Tags: c#, .net, api, windows-installer

i have started an installation from msi with MsiInstallProduct. 
Furthermore i have set a MsiSetInternalUI and MsiSetExternalUIRecord.

How can i tell the installation to stop and perform a rollback.

Have i to perform MsiDoAction with a special command?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to cause (or simulate) a user canceling the installation, then you need to return `ERROR_INSTALL_USEREXIT` from your UI's callback function. This only works in response to some of the messages your callback function will receive.